# Can someone please tell me why I'm not understanding scope in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You'll have to forgive me -- I'm a seasoned Java programmer, but still struggling with the semantic differences between the languages!

I have a small JavaScript object constructor. It includes a jQuery function which gets a small piece of Ajax data. When the data gets returned, I want to make use of it in conjunction with a variable (renderMode) defined at the top of the object constructor but, presumably because of function block closure, I am getting 'undefined'.

1. Can someone give me a corrected piece of code which shows me how to access renderMode inside of function(data)
2. Almost as important, can someone explain to me why what I did doesn't work !

Here's the example:

```
function AsyncRequest() {
    this.renderMode = RenderMode.NONE;
    this.setId = setId;

    function setId(v) {
        this.id = v;
    }
    this.setURL = setURL;

    function setURL(v) {
        this.URL = v;
    }

    this.render = render;

    function render(element) {
        $.get(
            this.URL,
            function (data) {
                // The data comes back just fine ...
                // ... and I know a value was previously assigned to renderMode
                // ... in this instance of AsyncRequest, but how do I get at it ?
                console.log("Render mode: " + this.renderMode); // this.renderMode is undefined
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a alias, try `var self = this;` before the get, and use `self` inside the get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in Java, `this` in JavaScript is determined primarily by **how** a function is called, not where it's defined. (ES6 will add a way to have `this` lexically-bound, but for now it's primarily bound by the function call.) So the callback you're passing into `$.get` is getting called with `this` not referring to the object you expect.

You can solve this by using the fact you have a closure:

```
function render(element) {
    var self = this;  // <=== Note
    $.get(
        this.URL,
        function (data) {
            console.log("Render mode: " + self.renderMode);
            // Note ----------------------^
        }
    );
}
```

There, we're remembering what `this` was when `render` was called in a variable called `self` (the name doesn't matter), and then using the fact that the callback function is a closure over the context of the call to `render`, and so we have access to the `self` variable.

You can also solve it with ES5's `Function#bind`:

```
function render(element) {
    $.get(
        this.URL,
        function (data) {
            console.log("Render mode: " + this.renderMode); // this.renderMode is undefined
        }.bind(this) // <== Note
    );
}
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, calls the original function with `this` set to the value you give it.

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: Some naming conventions prefer referencing `this` with `_this`, but as noted, the name doesn't really matter. It's all about the closure.

Comment: @jwal: Indeed, `self`, `_this`, `that` (which I find bizarre), `me`, all are common. I typically use something that relates to what `this` is, e.g. `dog` or `thingy` or `whatsit`...

Comment: Thanks. I'd much rather find these things out myself by having a play in a sandbox, but sometimes commercial pressures just don't allow that freedom of time - so I appreciate this, even though it may appear like a simple correction to you!If you were to suggest just one book (or series of tutorials) for me that covers these 'slightly beyond the basics' aspects of JS, what would it be ?

Comment: @user3206526: Oh, it may be basic, but it's *the* issue people trip over in JavaScript. I've blogged about many of the things that surprised me on my learning curve with JavaScript coming from more class-based languages, you might consider starting with the oldest of [the posts with this tag](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/search/label/javascript) and working forward. If you're going to do class-like things, check out [this doc page](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/wiki/ComparisonWithPlainJavaScript) for my `Lineage` script (and/or consider using the script).

Comment: @user3206526: In terms of books or tutorials, I found *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* by Flanagan to be good (but very traditional and long). A lot of people like Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts* (and the articles on [his website](http://javascript.crockford.com/). He's a smart, well-informed person, and worth reading, but he has a habit of stating his opinion as fact, to the cost of the writing (and in particular, the section on inheritance in TGP, which has an outright misstatement). Read for the information and make up your own mind about things. :-)

Comment: @user3206526: And finally, I've heard really good things about Marijn Haverbeke's [*Eloquent JavaScript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/), both the site and the book.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a var for "this" in the main function:

```
function AsyncRequest() {
    var self = this;
    self.renderMode = RenderMode.NONE;
    self.setId = setId;
    ...

    function render(element) {
        $.get(
            self.URL,
            function (data) {
                console.log("Render mode: ", self.renderMode);
            }
        );
    } 
}
```